# Access denied for copied objects in AWS S3

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to rename some of my S3 objects (from xxx.JPG to xxx.jpg).

Since we can't rename them using .NET AWSSDK.S3 API I copy the files with a different key name.

The new objects get listed on S3 Console, but I cant access their URL ("Make Public" button doesn't seen to work either).

```
<Error>
   <script id="tinyhippos-injected"/>
   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Access Denied</Message>
   <RequestId>496D3070***</RequestId>
   <HostId>
      zZOOgc5BCSmdIwaTy/wyOKHPU/xo32feTwfW***
   </HostId>
</Error>
```

The original objects have "Server-side encryption: None" but the new ones have "Server-side encryption: Access denied" as shown at the S3 Console.

I just can't understand why the new ones get this server-side encryption. I don't even know if that's the reason why I can't access their URL.

My C# code:

```
private const string sourceBucket = "***";
private const string destinationBucket = "***";
private const string objectKey = "***/image.JPG";
private const string destObjectKey = "***/image.jpg";

private static readonly RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.SAEast1;
private static IAmazonS3 s3Client;

private static async Task CopyingObjectAsync()
{
    try
    {
        s3Client = new AmazonS3Client("***", "***", RegionEndpoint.SAEast1);

        CopyObjectRequest request = new CopyObjectRequest
        {
            SourceBucket = sourceBucket,
            SourceKey = objectKey,
            DestinationBucket = destinationBucket,
            DestinationKey = destObjectKey,
            ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.None,

        };
        CopyObjectResponse response = await s3Client.CopyObjectAsync(request);
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(bucketRegion);
    Console.WriteLine("Copying an object");
    CopyingObjectAsync().Wait();
}
```

I even set the bucket public just to make sure it isn't the reason I can't access the new objects. No success.

Do you guys know what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Try passing a [CannedAccessControlList (AWS SDK for Java)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/CannedAccessControlList.html) of `BucketOwnerFullControl`

Comment: Are these buckets in 2 different AWS accounts? See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-owner-access/

Comment: Check the ownership information.

Comment: They are In the same account. Acctually, in the same bucket and folder.

Comment: They both have the same ownership

Comment: I’ll try that, John Rotenstein

Comment: I put "CannedACL = S3CannedACL.BucketOwnerFullControl" and now "Server-side encryption" shows "None", but I still don't have access to the file. Apparently both files (the original and the copied one) have the same attributes.

Answer (score 1):

CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead